# How to use Apache Camel to get web page HTML

Tags: apache-camel

I want to do nothing more than use Camel to get the HTML of a web page and save it as a local text file. I have tried the below but it doesn't work - it never hits the process code and no file shows up. This seems like it should be fairly simple. What am I doing wrong?

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure()
    {
       from("jetty:https://2001:4998:124:1507::f001") // www.yahoo.com IP address
       .process(new Processor() {
           public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
            {
               System.out.println( "Name="+ exchange.getIn().getBody() );              
            }
                
         })
       .to("file:C:\\temp\\folder2?fileName=web.txt");
    }
  });
       
      context.start();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      context.stop();
      System.out.println( "Done" );
```

Answer (score 1):

`from("jetty:https://....")` configures the Jetty consumer, which acts as a web server.

You should use a producer, E.g `to("jetty:https://...")`, to make client requests. Things can be simplified a bit by using the `camel-http` component instead of Jetty by adding a dependency like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    <version>your-camel-vesion-here</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the route could look like this. It uses the `timer` component to initiate the HTTP call:

```java
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:getHtml?repeatCount=1")
            .to("https://www.yahoo.com")
            .to("file:C:\\temp\\folder2?fileName=web.txt");
    }
});
```

If you're using Camel 3.x then you'll also need to add a dependency for `camel-timer` to make the example work.

Comment: OK, it works and I thank you. I'm just trying to wrap my head around this. I know when building a route Camel first requires a consumer component in the first() call. Since the doc says that only a consumer is supported in timer I guess that is satisfied. Since a producer is required for the to() method is "https" considered to be part of the http component?

Comment: Yes, the camel-http component supports 2 URI schemes. http & https.